# browserify / webpackify all the files in a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, browserify, babeljs

Is it possible to `browserify`/ `webpackify` all the files in a directory;

from

```
src
|____a.js
|____b.js
.
.
```

to

```
dist
|____a.js // browser compatible code
|____b.js // browser compatible code
.
.
```

as individual standalone files; *not bundled into one*, form `cli/binary`, just from `npm scripts` via `babel` w/o `grunt/gulp` etc.

**These files are top level files, which are importing modular ones and will be consumed independently**

Comment: That would mean each one of your dist files would incorporate all of its' dependencies + webpack specific code. I wouldn't recommend it (for the sake of your users)!

Comment: @MattLo I am aware of it, but they will be consumed independently. There are the top level files, which are importing modular ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set an entry for each like this:

```
{
  entry: [
    foo: '<path to foo>',
    bar: '<path to bar>'
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
}
```

This will output a separate bundle for each entry.

An alternative way to solve this would be to return an array of configurations (webpack can pick that up). In this case each configuration would have a single entry. The advantage of doing this is that you could set up a little script to evaluate the separate configurations in parallel against webpack's Node API.